# How to view html files stored in aws s3 bucket in html format?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-hosting

I want to store some reports in aws s3 bucket. Every day I will generate those reports which are basically folders consisting of a html file and some css and xml files. I want to upload the folder to a bucket a generate a link for that html file. Accessing the link from any browser people should see the file in proper rendered format. How to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You are going to want to turn on the 'static website' options for the bucket - its that simple.

> To host a static website, you configure an Amazon S3 bucket for
>   website hosting and then upload your website content to the bucket.
>   For more information, see Configuring a Bucket for Website Hosting.
>   This bucket must have public read access. It is intentional that
>   everyone in the world will have read access to this bucket. To learn
>   how to configure public read access for your bucket, see Permissions
>   Required for Website Access.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html